# TinyMce and laravel livewire

Tags: tinymce

I am using laravel livewire and when i save the data from tinymce editor, it turned to empty.  I can see the value in the console of the browser but when it is saved to my livewire component, it becomes null.

```
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#description',
        allow_conditional_comments: true,
        setup: function(editor) {
            editor.on('init change', function() {
                editor.save();
            });
            editor.on('change', function(e) {
                console.log(tinymce.activeEditor.getContent());
                var content = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();
                document.getElementById('description').value = content;
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

I tried to use the @this.set('description', tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent());, but error comes out showing undeclared instance

Solution or example how to save data from tinymce editor using livewire and tinymce

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your #description textarea is correctly bound to a Livewire property. For instance, if your Livewire component has a property named $description, your textarea should be like:

```
<textarea id="description" wire:model="description"></textarea>
```

Modify the TinyMCE initialization script to properly update the Livewire property. The error you are encountering with @this.set might be due to the context in which it is being called. To ensure it's called correctly, you can use an arrow function which doesn't have its own this binding.

Here's an updated version of your script:

```
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#description',
        allow_conditional_comments: true,
        setup: function (editor) {
            editor.on('init change', function () {
                editor.save();
            });
            editor.on('change', function (e) {
                var content = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();
                @this.set('description', content);
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

In this script, @this.set('description', content); is used to update the Livewire component's description property whenever the content of TinyMCE changes.